# Why does direct initializing a base class member from a prvalue require a copy or move constructor?

Tags: c++, direct-initialization

It is well known that for a class with deleted copy and move constructors, it is still possible to direct initialize an object from a prvalue such as the return value of a function. For example, this compiles:

```
struct B {
  B(int i, std::string s) {}
  B(const B&) = delete;
};

B Factory() {
  return {1, "ss"};
}

int main() {
  B obj(Factory());
  return 0;
}
```

However, if I add:

```
struct D : public B {
  D() : B(Factory()) {}
};
```

I get an error: *main.cpp:22:40: error: use of deleted function ‘B::B(const B&)’*

Why is this?  The standard says (11.9.4(7)):

> The *expression-list* or *braced-init-list* in a *mem-initializer* is used to initialize the designated subobject (or, in the case of a delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the initialization rules of 9.4 for direct-initialization.

And Section 9.4(17.6.1) covers the case of intializing by a prvalue of the same type, and it makes no exception for a base class member:

> If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is
> the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the
> destination object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that according to the standard there shouldn't be a copy/move constructor call here. The `B` subobject ought to be directly initialized by `{1, "ss"}` as in the other cases of mandatory copy elision you mentioned.

However, that is not actually implementable because of the potential padding reuse of parts of the base class subobject that the function `Factory` doesn't know about and might therefore unintentionally overwrite.

See [CWG issue 2403](https://wg21.link/cwg2403).

Comment: I accepted the answer because of the reference to the CWG issue, but I'm not clear on why it's not implementable.  IIUC the problem is that `Factory` may overwrite some tail padding that `D` might potentially be using for its own data members.  However, the base class member is initialized before any other member, so any overwriting shouldn't matter, should it?  Also, why would copying or moving work correctly in this case?  The copy/move ctor wouldn't know whether the object it's constructing is standalone or subobject, presumably.  Could you please expand a bit on the problematic scenario?